# Getting error on setOnItemClickListener method android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

In my app I am trying to parse json object to show the related information in recyclerview. I have implented deserialization of object using gson Library. Now I want to set click on each of the item to show the details information of the list. for this try to implement setOnItemClicklistener to recyclerView. but I do not why I am getting this message Error:(102, 29) error: cannot find symbol method setOnItemClickListener(). Here is my complete code of Main Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.testgrid.MainActivity;
import com.testgrid.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<MyColleageModel> colleagueObject;
InputStream is;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    new JSONTask().execute();
  }

  public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<MyColleageModel>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MyColleageModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

        colleagueObject = new ArrayList<MyColleageModel>();

        try {

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("contacts");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                MyColleageModel model = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), MyColleageModel.class);


                colleagueObject.add(model);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<MyColleageModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(colleagueObject, getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          //Problem in this setOnItemClickListener
            recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { //problem in this line
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    MyColleageModel myColleageModel=result.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyColleaguesPage.this, DetailMyColleague.class);
                    intent.putExtra("contacts", new Gson().toJson(myColleageModel));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not able to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
 }

    private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

           ................
        return json;

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `setOnItemClickListener` on a recyclerView. Instead, use `addOnItemTouchListener`. You should create a new class implementing `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` .See [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) for reference.

Comment: How can implement this in my code. I am very new in nadroid developing. could you plaese explain how can I implement it here

Comment: You can check section 2.2 & 2.3 in [this](https://tutorialwing.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial-example/) blog.